# Group selectors javascript with concatenation

Tags: javascript

Can you group those into one line, I know how to do this without concatenation but with, not working.

```
$('#vda'+event.target.id).remove();
$('#a'+event.target.id).remove();
$('#'+event.target.id).remove();
$('#da'+event.target.id).remove();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is your one liner.

```
$(
    '#vda' + event.target.id +
    ', #a' + event.target.id + 
    ', #' + event.target.id +
    ', #da' + event.target.id
).remove();
```

it seems more, but I divided to better readability.

https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/ here is the documentation for multiple selector of jQuery

Comment: If you paste your one line into the code at http://codepen.io/lakhjo/pen/NrbqmB           The remove button doesn't work anymore. I think the code you provided doesn't work can you try.

Comment: just fixed it, please test with new code I provided. here is working demo... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKbYjX

Comment: here it generates a long string with selector seperated by commas, before there was separate arguments for each selector. I checked Jquery's documentation then I see my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var str = ['#vda', '#a', '#', '#da'].join(event.target.id + ',') + event.target.id;
$(str).remove();
```

**The join() method joins all elements of an array into a string.**

> str = arr.join([separator = ','])

or you can use `reduce` function

```
var str = ['#vda', '#a', '#', '#da'].reduce(function(p,c, i,arr){
   if(i !== arr.length - 1)
       return p + event.target.id + ',' + c
   else
      return p + event.target.id+ ',' + c + event.target.id
});

$(str).remove();
```

Comment: I guess `.map` is more suited for such requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have any extra elements with similar IDs, you can try ends with pattern selector:

`$("[id$='pattern']")`

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  var target = "test"; // e.target.id
  $('[id$="test"]').remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="test">test</div>
  <div id="atest">atest</div>
  <div id="datest">datest</div>
  <div id="vdatest">vdatest</div>
</div>
<button id="btn">Test</button>
```

You can try to make an array of all possible combinations and use `map` + `join` to get string

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  var target = "test"; // e.target.id
  var selector_list = ["#", "#a", "#da", "#vda"];
  var el_str = selector_list.map(function(item) {
    return item + target;
  }).join();
  console.log(el_str);
  $(el_str).remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="test">test</div>
  <div id="atest">atest</div>
  <div id="datest">datest</div>
  <div id="vdatest">vdatest</div>
</div>
<button id="btn">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery** allows you to select as you do in CSS

So for the sake of an example, if you want to make a selector that matches all `div`s with `test` class, and all the `p` elements as well, in CSS you would select them using:

```
div.test, p { property:value }
```

In **jQuery**, do the same thing:

```
$("div.test, p").remove()
```

So you can just replace the `div.test, p` with whatever you selector you like

[Here's a nice reference for CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
['vda','a','',da].forEach(function(val,key){

    $('#'+event.target.id).remove();    

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for a record, you can do with pure JS selector API in ES6 style as follows;

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(['#vda','#a','#','#da'].join(",")].forEach(e => e.parentElement.removeChild(e));
```